# This code is directly from a textbook for Cisco Devnet yet presents a syntax error in python 3.8.1 shell. Why? I tried viewing text in notepad++

Tags: while-loop, printing, syntax, conditional-statements

while True:
string = input('Enter some text to print. \nType "done" to quit>')
if string == 'done':
break
print(string)
print('Done!')

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icF4n.png)

[Image after idz's suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZgF1.png)

Comment: Questions that contain nothing in the post body but a code dump (especially when you've made no attempt to format it at all) don't do well here. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: I am clearly new. What is a code dump? This is just sample code from a tutorial I purchased from cisco that I tried to follow along with? I googled code dump with varying answers.

Comment: A *code dump* is exactly that - someone just *dumping code* into a post with nothing else in the body. *clearly new* makes no difference; you're expected to follow the same guidelines as everyone else. Have you followed the links I posted for you yet to learn what our expectations are? I'd start with [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you wrote:

```py
while true:
```

instead of

```py
while True:
```

However, if you are using Python 2 you should be aware that `input` will attempt to evaluate what you type in as Python. Depending on what your aim is, you may want to use `raw_input` instead. This is not an issue if your are using Python 3.

Comment: Thank you idz. I did try capitalizing the T in true to no avail unfortunately. I tried running the code minus the last print statement and it worked so I think the last print statement is the culprit.

Comment: @BlackBlade glad you figured it out. I'm not sure what environment your screenshots are from but (1) it would be good to include that information in your questions (2) read all of Ken White's comments... they really will help you get a quicker answer (3) if you run this code outside whatever environment you are currently in you **will** get bitten by the `True` vs. `true`.